# Relative masses of Binary Systems

Tags: science-fiction, orbital-mechanics, astrophysics

I'm writing a sci-fi novel and I have an some astrophysics questions. First, is it possible for a binary system to be made up of a large gaseous planet and a dwarf star?

I know it's possible to have two stars orbit each other, and a planet around those (since there is still a center of mass that the system orbits) but could one of the stars be replaced with a planet of sufficient mass without the planet becoming a star itself?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please ready our [help] to understand our policies. You are supposed, among the others, to ask only one question per post, do and show some preliminary research and the question should be closely scoped. Please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: It's also customary to wait 24-48 hours before awarding the green tick, as the international audience then gets a chance to answer. (In this case, you're unlikely to get a better answer if you wait, so don't worry).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mass of Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_mass) is around $\approx 10^{-4} M_{sun}$.

A [super-jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Jupiter) type of planet, is roughly $80$ times the mass of Jupiter, so, $\approx 10^{-2} M_{sun}$.

The [least massive white dwarf star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_star_extremes#Size_and_mass), is roughly $\approx 0.17 M_{sun}$.

So we are talking about a mass ratio of roughly $5\%$.
According to wikipedia, the [Charon-Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charon_(moon)#Classification) orbit in the solar system is considered a binary system, and Charon has $12\%$ the mass of Pluto.

So, I didn't do any calculations to locate the center of mass, in order to make sure it is located outside the bodies, and thus claim it as a binary system, but, looking at these data, it looks promising, and it seems to indicate it is possible to have a binary system made of a star and a planet [a very small dwarf star, and a super-jupiter planet].

---

**However..** It might not look like a binary system, even if it is. For instance, this is Charon-Pluto:

[image]